# How i can make Discord bot that will check player's inventory Fortnite with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

First i know that should to get authorization code.

I put client id into the link and click it. I don't know how to get client id, i've used another discord bot.
Next i get auth id and input it in discord chat while bot listening and it show me detailed stats:
avatar, lvl, skins, gliders, seasons etc.
[image: Generate Link]

I wanna it be like this

[image]

What api should i use and how?